# Groovy StremMarkupBuilder -> set Namespace on bind

Tags: xml, groovy, namespaces

I'm struggling setting the namespace when using the Groovy StreamMarkupBuilder.

I know that I can set the namespace like:

```
builder.bind {
mkp.xmlDeclaration()
mkp.declareNamespace('ns0':'http://test.com')
```

I need to create a more complex output message and therefore I was using separate methods to construct the XML message.

here is my starting point to call the build root method which then call separate other methods defining parts of my target XML

```
def xml = markupBuilder.bind { builder -> buildRoot builder  }
```

How would be the best way to define and set the namespace e.g. already for the root tag "TargetMsg"?

Here a sample how I would construct the coding later on:

```
import groovy.util.slurpersupport.GPathResult
import groovy.xml.*


class test {
    static main(args) {
        def result = doMapping()
    }


    static String doMapping(GPathResult source) {
        def markupBuilder = new StreamingMarkupBuilder()

        // Build Target Message

        def xml = markupBuilder.bind { builder -> buildRoot builder  }
        println XmlUtil.serialize(xml)
        return XmlUtil.serialize(xml)

    }

    static buildRoot(
        builder){

        def target = builder.TargetMsg{
            element1    "test1"
            element2    "test"

        }
    }
```

Thanks Marco

Comment: Can you show the input data and expected xml?

Comment: You can run the Script without Input. I would expect the Target message like the following: <ns0:TargetMsg xmlns:ns0="http://test.com"><element1>test1 </element1><element2>test2</element2></ns0:TargetMsg>